# Android, how to disable the showing "loading..." when loading a gridview?

Tags: android, gridview, loading

When my gridview loading content, it will always show a "loading..." string in grid item.

How can I disable it? so I want to keep the grid as original style when loading something.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with AsyncTask? The depth of my answer will depend on this.

Comment: I not wondering a async loading, I just want to hide the String "loading" in gridview. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I do.

Have a Frame Layout or a Relative Layout containing both the GridView and a TextView (fill_parent with text "Loading..." in the center).

During your AsyncTask, onPreExcute set the visibility of the gridView to `View.GONE` and the textview to Visible, and during onPostExecute, switch back the visibility of GridView to Visible and turn off the visibility of the textview.

Instead of a TextView it can also be a composite layout containing a Progress Bar and a text view.

This is also how "Empty View" works. (atleast for old versions)